# heroku migrate: django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server failed

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I am a student learning on full-stack web development.

I am very new to coding and would need  help with following.

I am trying to deploy my Django app to Heroku.
Previously was using sqlite3 - then I did migration to postgre.

Now I am trying to run the code `heroku run python manage.py migrate` but I am having error or django.db.utils.OperationError: connection to server, port 5433 failed.

I went to pgadmin4, looked at properties of my Postgre server and port is 5433 - so I changed to 5433. I believed it's due to my installation of previous version of postgre which took up default 5432 port.

Anyway, I have no issues when i `py manage.py runserver`. Everything works properly.

So I did `heroku create` - after that, there's application error when i try to access the website. Not sure if it's supposed to be error at this point of stage.

Next step should be `heroku run python manage.py migrate` where the error occurs.

Below is my code for settings.py:

```html
"""
Django settings for recipe_project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.2.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('DJANGO_SECRET_KEY', 'django-insecure-aoc9h$2+(d=$j^d6y5!1i=mc8p2yk)9rj&2woaje1oant$svhv')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1', '.herokuapp.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # recipe_project-related apps
    'recipe',
    'user',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'recipe_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'recipe_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

# DATABASES = {
#     'default': {
#         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
#         'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
#     }
# }

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'test',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static']

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

# Heroku: Update database configuration from $DATABASE_URL.
import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://postgres:password@localhost:5433/test')
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

# DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://user:pass@localhost/test')}
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5a5kK.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your django app for Heroku. Add this below your settings.py

```
import django_heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Also you may need to Provision Heroku Postgres for your django app. You can do this by following the steps in https://dev.to/prisma/how-to-setup-a-free-postgresql-database-on-heroku-1dc1